# How to figure out which enum items are "hidden" in an integer value

Tags: c#, enums

We have a database where one of the columns contains composite enum integer values. We need to strip all these values (if they have it) of a specific enum integer value, but leave the rest in place.

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum
{
    Enum1 = 1,
    Enum2 = 2,
    Enum3 = 4,
    Enum4 = 8,
}
```

In the database we find

```
Row    MyEnumSettings
1      3                   (Enum1 | Enum2)
2      8                   (Enum4)
3      6                   (Enum2 | Enum3)
4      14                  (Enum2 | Enum3 | Enum4)
```

We want to remove Enum3 from every row and end up with

```
Row    MyEnumSettings
1      3                   (no change)
2      8                   (no chnage)
3      2                   (removed Enum3)
4      10                  (removed Enum3)
```

We can use Enum.IsDefined to check if an integer is part of an enum (not sure if it works on composite integer values..). But, how do we check if a given integer value contains a specific part of an enum?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should remove the enum if they are bitwisely added:

```
Value &= ~Enum3
```

Basically you need to bitwisely negate the Enum3 which leads to a negative mask, and apply bitwise AND to exclude the bit which is 0.

The opposite operation is, if you need to add it back

```
Value |= Enum3
```

Comment: Great, will try that (no time now - but tomorrow).

Comment: To check a composite value, use value.HasFlag(MyEnum.Enum1) on each item in the enum to get the whole picture.